# Keypress anywhere to text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to mimic the functionality in the new Myspace. What happens is you can simply start typing and the UI changes to a "search". The characters entered are now within a large text field with auto complete showing results.

How do I detect a keypress anywhere on the page, not within a specific text field? 
How do I then show the text and/or focus on the text field with the text being entered?

Comment: you can use jQuery and $("#text-field").focus(), and autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I was looking at keypress but needed it to work over the entire UI without the user having to select the text field directly. Keypress seems like it looks for a specific key when I need it to work on any key. That make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" value="type here"/><br/>
<textarea>type here</textarea><br/>
<input type="text" value="don't type here" class="searchbox"/><br/>
```

​
JavaScript (jQuery) Code

```
$( document ).on( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
    var nodeName = ev.target.nodeName;

    if ( 'INPUT' == nodeName || 'TEXTAREA' == nodeName ) {
        return;
    }
    $( '.searchbox' ).val( '' ).trigger( 'focus' );
} );​
```

and here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/PThCS/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. @bukfixart can you assist me in tying it into this: http://jsfiddle.net/tmoura/aECPL/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
function keydown(){
    //key was pressed
}  
document.onkeydown=keydown;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/djsQ8/1/

Comment: Thats what I'm looking for now how do I set the focus on the text field?

Answer (score 1):

Works only for the first time. May be this is what you want. With jQuery it would be much easier and better. But first, a pure JavaScript.

**Update** - Nopes. Posting jQuery only as you wanted, check fiddle for JavaScript

```
var firstTyped = false,
    field = $('#field');

function startTyping(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (firstTyped) {
        $(document).unbind('keypress', startTyping);                      
    }
    firstTyped = true;
    field
        .fadeIn(200)
        .focus()
}
$(document).keypress(startTyping);
```

Just like Google Search. you can also hide the field initially and then show on first character type.

http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/ztKLA/

**Update**:

For the scenario you mentioned in your comment, I think the following **pseudo-code** might be useful

```
$(yourform).submit(function() {
    ....
    // Submit Successful
    // Reset the text field and bind the event again:
    field.val('').hide();
    $(document).keypress(startTyping);
});
```

Comment: This is somewhat what I was looking for. Yet, I need it to work after a user clicks a submit button. It would then need to reset. Would you have any info on the Jquery solution? The application I'm working on will have the user entering into a text field multiple times. I'm just trying to reduce the user having to click on the text field directly in order to enter text.

Comment: @Tony, look at the link at the bottom of the solution, jsFiddle link. It has both jQuery and JavaScript. Updating my answer for you for the **after the submit button part**

Comment: this is what what I have so far. http://jsfiddle.net/tmoura/aECPL/1/  after selecting submit the functionality resets.

Comment: @Tony, Check this - http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/j7Mzq/. Kindly accept my answer if worked. Kindly provide more details if I am not able to understand your secenario